Question in proof of Proposition 10.24 in "Lectures on von Neumann algebras"
Consider the following fragment from the book "Lectures on von Neumann algebras" by Stratila and Zsido (see section 10.24 p361):
The context is as follows: we fix a hyperstandard von Neumann algebra, in the sense of the following definition:

I would like to understand the proof of the following:


I understand everything in the proof except the two boxed (in red) equalities. Here, given $\xi \in \mathscr{H}$, we write
$p_\xi\in \mathscr{M}$ for the projection on $[\mathscr{M}'\xi]$ and $p_\xi'\in \mathscr{M}'$ for the projection on $[\mathscr{M}\xi]$.
Thanks in advance for your help!

For the first inequality, this is functional calculus - $\Delta^{1/4}$ is an injective, positive operator. For any positive real number $r > 0$, we have $\frac{1}{2}(r + r^{-1}) \geq 1$, so $\frac{1}{2}(\Delta^{1/4} + \Delta^{-1/4}) \geq 1$, by functional calculus. Thus, $\langle \frac{1}{2}(\Delta^{1/4} + \Delta^{-1/4})\xi|\xi \rangle \geq \langle \xi|\xi \rangle = \|\xi\|^2$ for any vector $\xi$ (in the appropriate domain).
For the second equality, we prove the following: suppose $\xi, \eta \in \mathfrak{B}$ is s.t. $p_\xi \perp p_\eta$, $p_\xi + p_\eta = 1$, then $p’_{\xi + \eta} = 1$. Indeed, in this case we have $p_\xi(\eta) = 0$, so $\xi = p_\xi(\xi + \eta) \in [\mathcal{M}(\xi + \eta)] = p’_{\xi + \eta}\mathcal{H}$. Thus,
$$p’_{\xi + \eta}(m\xi) = mp’_{\xi + \eta}(\xi) = m\xi$$
That is, $p’_{\xi + \eta} p'_\xi = p'_\xi$. We now note that, as $\xi \in \mathfrak{B}$, we have $Jp'_\xi J\xi = Jp'_\xi \xi = J\xi = \xi$, i.e., $Jp'_\xi J$ is a projection in $\mathcal{M}'' = \mathcal{M}$ which sends $\xi$ to itself, whence it must majorize $p_\xi$. Similarly, $Jp_\xi J \geq p'_\xi$, so $Jp'_\xi J \leq p_\xi$ as well, i.e., $Jp'_\xi J = p_\xi$. But then,
$$p_\xi = Jp'_\xi J = Jp’_{\xi + \eta} p'_\xi J = Jp’_{\xi + \eta}JJp'_\xi J = Jp’_{\xi + \eta}Jp_\xi$$
Similarly, we also have $p_\eta = Jp’_{\xi + \eta}Jp_\eta$. But this implies,
$$1 = p_\xi + p_\eta = Jp’_{\xi + \eta}Jp_\xi + Jp’_{\xi + \eta}Jp_\eta = Jp’_{\xi + \eta}J$$
So $p’_{\xi + \eta} = JJp’_{\xi + \eta}JJ = J1J = 1$ as well.

Thanks for your answer. Doesn't $p_{\xi+\eta}'(m\xi) = m\xi$ not imply that $p_{\xi+\eta}' p_\xi' = p_\xi'$ (instead of what you wrote)?

@Andromeda You’re right. The second part doesn’t work. I’ll think about this more.

@Andromeda Fixed.

Thanks! If you have time and are interested, I have some other questions about this book :)
